# Office 365 Add-in with Oauth2 Authentication

Tags: azure, office365, outlook-addin, office365-apps

I am making Office 365 add-in for Outlook web and SharePoint. As per the documentation, I need a developer account to register my add-in. The developer account for company is for $99.

I also wanted to authenticate user using his office 365 subscription. The documentation tells that an Azure account is needed for office 365 authentication, in which the app will be registered. Azure account is for $99 for company.

Now my question is that, as I have to register office 365 add-in and also enable authentication, do I need to buy both accounts each for $99 that cost $198. Or only one account serves my purpose ? It will be really helpful if any one having experience with office add-in can suggest some good resource to do this.

Answer (score 1):

After you have the Office 365 developer account, you don't have to buy the Azure subscription to register the app to the Azure Active Directory. Because the Office 365 account already have a free subscription to Azure Active Directory.

And to activate this subscription and access the Azure management portal, you have to complete a one-time registration process. Afterward, you can access Azure AD from your Microsoft service that uses it(refer [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832618.aspx) about detail).

And it is recommend that you register the app through the Application Registration Portal at http://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ since it supports 'V2' which allow developers to write apps that accept sign-in from both Microsoft Accounts and Azure AD accounts, using a single auth endpoint([V2 endpoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-compare/)).

Comment: I also do not need Microsoft Developer Account? Office  365 developer account will do all for me (Register Office 354 Add-in, authentication, and app listing in Office 365 store)?

Comment: Would you minding more detail about the Microsoft Developer Account? As far as I know, the the Office 365 developer account is enough for us developing the Office add-in. And the Microsoft also provide **one year FREE subscription for an Office 365 Development instance** to get the **free** Office 365 developer account through **Office 365 Dev Program**. Please refer [here](http://dev.office.com/devprogram) about the detail.